# Vertically aligning an expander button to the top of a DataGridRowHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander, datagridrowheader

In a DataGrid I have added an Expander to the row headers, which works fine functionally, however when expanded it centers vertically.

I would like it to remain at the top of the header where it was clicked in the first place.

What am I missing here?

```
<DataGrid Name="dgAudit" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding GEOM_ASSET_OC_LIST}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
          >
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Template="{StaticResource NewExpander}"
                      OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                      Header=""
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
                      >
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

    <DataGrid.Columns>...
```

Here is the main template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NewExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <DockPanel>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" 
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      Template="{StaticResource AnimatedExpanderButtonTemp}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                      Padding="0.5,0">
        </ToggleButton>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the template for animation:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AnimatedExpanderButtonTemp" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="ExpanderButtonBorder"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Ellipse Name="Circle"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Stroke="DarkGray"
                     Fill="LightGray"
                     Width="15"
                     Height="15"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 8,1.5"
                  Stroke="#FF666666"
                  StrokeThickness="2"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                 Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                         To="180"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF3C7FB1" TargetName="Circle"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#222" TargetName="Arrow"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF526C7B" TargetName="Circle"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"  Value="1.5" TargetName="Circle"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF003366" TargetName="Arrow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here are the expand collapse events:

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual) 
    if (vis is DataGridRow) 
    { 
        var row = (DataGridRow)vis; 
        row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; 
        break; 
    } 
} 

private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual) 
    if (vis is DataGridRow) 
    { 
        var row = (DataGridRow)vis; 
        row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: "centers vertically"? What does this mean? Your issue os not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What it means is when the row expands to display the row details the row header in turn expands and the expander button in the row header drops because it's vertical alignment is somehow set to the Center. I want the expander button to remain at the top of the header.

Comment: There is no content in your Expander so your issue is still not reproducible...please refer to the link.

Comment: The expander's content gets populated through the control templates, it is replicatible

Comment: No, the NewExpander ControlTemplate only contains a ToggleButton but no ContentPresenter and you haven't posted the code for your event handlers.

Comment: And it doesn't need a content presenter to work, I'm just using the toggle button, but we're moving away from the original question so lets get back on track. Just add a row to the datagrid with a row height of 50. Can you see the toggle button vertically align to the center.

Comment: Or create a row with row details and remove RowDetailsVisibilityMode in the DataGrid tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContentPresenter` in the default `DataGridRowHeader` template has a hard-coded `VericalAlignment` of `Center`. You need to modify the template to be able to fix this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2VisibilityConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="RowHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNS"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}"
                       xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsSelected="{TemplateBinding IsRowSelected}" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Control SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Template="{Binding ValidationErrorTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Visibility="{Binding (Validation.HasError), Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_TopHeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource RowHeaderGripperStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_BottomHeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource RowHeaderGripperStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Don't fortget to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll`.

Comment: Works also with PresentationFramework.Aero.dll on Windows 7 (where Aero2 doesn't work).